# Caching support for mutitenant enviornment

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache, multi-tenant

I have a use-case where I want to "partition" the cache. I've tried using spring annotation based caching. It works fine for a single tenant application.

E.g. The name of the cache in @Cachable is fine, but I want the interceptor to call a CacheResolver class which resolves the end-cache name based on some other contextual metadata I provide through my application.(For example tenant identifier)

The use-case for this is that I want several cache instances which cache the same info, but several different instances to have an isolated instance for each tenant (multitenant environment). This way I can size them suitable for each tenant - but still keep my code/metainfo quite so clean.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From your post, IMHO, you should consider using some distributed caching mechanism like `AppFabric` or `memcache`.

Comment: @saravanan Thanks. I was able to solve this issue by adding a tenant specific identifier to the key values. AppFabric and memcache seems promising , I'll consider on the cache storage in the next phase. It is really easy to plugin an external cache storage when we use spring cache abstraction.

Comment: @apremalal Please put the example code for others help and even accept your answer.